# How to write code realizing this manual operation?

Tags: front-end, programming, output-formatting, notebooks, cells

I want to use the output of `N[E,15]`. However the output is really `` 2.71828182845904523533978449066641588615`15. `` if you copy the output and paste it in a new inline.
[image]
I just need the number as the appearance of the output, i.e. `2.71828182845905`. To get the value of `N[E,15]`, the operation **Edit►Copy As►Plain Text** is feasible. Then
I have a question that how to write some code using low-level notebook structure to realize this operation instead of manual operation. Wolfram Documentation tells me that `CopySpecial` is equivalent to **Edit ► Copy As**. But I don't know how to modify this command according to my purpose, `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], "CopySpecial", "PlainText"]] ``.
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The long number is the internal representation. What you see on the screen is formating done by frontend (which can be adjusted). If you do not want the long form, then you can do `N[E]` instead of `N[E,15]`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUIxb.png)  once you give the second argument to `N` then that what happens.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your comments. The above problem is related to my another problem. I need the solution of the above paradigmatic problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
N[Round[E, 10^-15], 15]

(* 2.71828182845905 *)
```

You can copy it with `CTRL+C` or by code `CopyToClipboard@N[Round[E, 10^-15], 15]`.

Or with code it can be simplified to `CopyToClipboard@ToString@N[E, 15]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use the command `N[Round[E, 10^-15], 15]`, copy and paste the output in a new inline. The result is ```2.718281828459045`15.```, I want to delete the last symbols **`15.**, how can I do?

Comment: So use the other code `CopyToClipboard@ToString@N[E, 15]`. After executing this code press `CTRL+V` on a new line and you get exactly what you want - `2.71828182845905`.

Comment: Press `CTRL+V`, the result is in text. It is better that the result is input.

Comment: No, it is not in the form of text/string, it is as normal input. What version of Mathematica do you use?

Comment: My current Mathematica is version 11.0.  I should update the Mathematica.

Comment: On version 13 it is copied without `""`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one more question, how to assign the pasted value to a variable by Mathematica?I use the command `e=Paste[]`, it is not workable.

Comment: I used more advanced Mathematica in another computer a moment ago.